# What stats should I be prioritizing/near-endgame questions in general

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

I'm a level 900 wizard in Gemcraft: Labyrinth, with around 8500 skill points. My general goal is to create a Y/O/L supergem that goes in a trap, with a B/C/P before it that slows/stuns/armor-shreds things to soften them up for the killing gem.

I used to play this game religiously, but fell out of it after not being sure how to proceed with high-level Endurance runs.

I have max stats in everything that has a cap except for Banisher (decreased banishment cost, but who needs that? If you're letting things leak, you're playing the game wrong), and Poison/Bloodbound masteries. 
Focus gives me 800% extra min/max mana, Replenish gives me 275% mana gain over time and kill, and Resonance gives me 225% extra damage. At this point, I'm not sure which stat I should be prioritizing. With a higher starting mana, it will cost much less to get more mana in the long run. Mana over time and per kill makes it easier to get better gems faster, and damage is...damage.

I'm also wondering how much summoning I should be doing during certain parts of the game; how many gems on which waves, and what grades should they be? When should I stop summoning? Also the ratio of orange to lime to yellow in the killgem, as well as when to squish out the orange. Other tips in general would be appreciated.

EDIT: I play with setting at max aside from Waves Get Tougher Faster.

Comment: I've used [this](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/76-gemcraft-labyrinth/topics/167433-my-guide-to-endurance-hardest-settings) as a guide in the past, but I've found it to be inefficient.